# Is it possible to manipulate the date in an Ansible Playbook

Tags: ansible

Am using the `ansible_date_time.hour` and `ansible_date_time.minute` in one of my playbooks.

But I need to add time on to these facts (or in a variable).. i.e. if `ansible_date_time.hour` returns 16 - I want to add a couple of hours, or if `ansible_date_time.minute` returns 40 - I want it to be 50..

Of course there is a ceiling of 23 and 59 for the hours and mins... as I thought about registering a variable from:

```
- name: Register HH  
  shell: date '+%H'
  register: HP_HH
- debug: msg="{{ HP_HH.stdout | int + 3 }}"
```

But obviously if my playbook runs at after 21:00 I am out of luck.

Does anyone have a suggestion or workaround?

Comment: Apologies - I am not trying to be vague.

I need the fact/variable to return the current time (hours) plus 2 hours OR the current time (minutes) plus 10 minutes. 

I did look at the filters documentation, but I didn't see anything which would achieve this.

Thanks again

Comment: Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45473547/512965

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK, there is no way to add/subtract time units out of the box in Ansible.

You can convert strings to `datetime` object with `to_datetime` filter (Ansible 2.2+).
You can calculate date difference. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42030944/2795592) answer.

But if you don't mind using a simple filter plugin, here you go:

Drop this code as `./filter_plugins/add_time.py` near your playbook:

```
import datetime

def add_time(dt, **kwargs):
    return dt + datetime.timedelta(**kwargs)

class FilterModule(object):

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'add_time': add_time
        }
```

And you can use your own `add_time` filter as follows:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Current datetime is {{ ansible_date_time.iso8601 }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "Current time +20 mins {{ ansible_date_time.iso8601[:19] | to_datetime(fmt) | add_time(minutes=20) }}"
      vars:
        fmt: "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
```

`add_time` has same parameters as [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) in Python.

Comment: Hi Konstantin,
Thank you very much for your response.. I think I am getting close..
However I need to split this into two variables..
+%Y-%m-%d and then +%H:%M

I did try that but it fails (my Python skills are non existent):

Comment: > - debug:
>       msg: "Current time +25 mins {{ ansible_date_time.iso8601[:19] | > to_datetime(fmt) | add_time(minutes=25) }}"
>    vars:
>        fmt: "%H:%M"

"the field 'args' has an invalid value , and could not be converted to an dict"

Thanks again for your help here :)

Comment: Format string for `to_datetime` filter should match argument string. If you want only `%H:%M`, you should cut that part from iso8610, like `ansible_date_time.iso8601[11:16]` – characters from 11th to 16th.

Comment: Hi Konstantin,
Thanks again for your response.. I am getting close.. 
Can you tell me if this only works with ansible_date_time.iso8601?
When I run it against ansible_date_time.date it returns "2017-05-08 00:10:00"..i.e. more than just the date - it includes the number of minutes added.
ansible_date_time.date returns 1900-01-01 and an obscure time/result.
Thanks again for your help sir

Comment: Please read [strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) documentation to understand how strings are converted to date objects and what each format directive means.

Comment: Thanks for the reply (and your patience!)
I *think* I am using the correct format directive...
"%Y-%m-%d" = date
"%H:%M" = time

Comment: Hi Konstantin,
Can you tell me - your method of manipulating the time will only work with ansible_date_time.iso8601? 
Even when I  use ansible_date_time.iso8601_basic_short - I get the same formatting results as above.
Could I trouble you for an example using iso8601_basic_short  or using ansible_date_time.date or ansible_date_time.time sir?
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this in my searching and the solution for me (in ansible 2.9) is much easier.

```
---
- name: test date math playbook
  hosts: localhost

  tasks: 
    - name: today
      debug:
        msg: "today is {{ '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'|strftime(ansible_date_time.epoch) }}"

    - name: one year ago
      debug:
        msg: "one-year-ago-today is {{ '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'|strftime( (ansible_date_time.epoch|int) - (60*60*24*365)) }}"
```

By converting to integer, you can do date math inline (with built in filters)