# Ansible - Increment date by 'X' days/minutes

Tags: datetime, ansible

The variable `ansible_date_time.date` gives the current date and time stamp, however I wish to increment this date by 'X' minutes/days. Is there any built in method or logic to do this?

The `-` operator seems to work with date operands, however there doesn't seem to be any straightforward way to increment a date.

I want to accomplish this in a yml script itself and not by using additional Python scripting as described in [Is it possible to manipulate the date in an Ansible Playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43769809/is-it-possible-to-manipulate-the-date-in-an-ansible-playbook)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43769809/is-it-possible-to-manipulate-the-date-in-an-ansible-playbook/43790398#43790398

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to manipulate the date in an Ansible Playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43769809/is-it-possible-to-manipulate-the-date-in-an-ansible-playbook)

Comment: Is there any inline function that can be used within yml file itself?

Comment: No, for this very reason I provided custom filter in the answer I linked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command module can be used as shown in the following snippet to increment the current date. This worked for me as expected.

```
- command: "date +'%d-%m-%Y' -d '+3 days'"
  register: result

- debug: msg="{{result.stdout}}"
```

This will return the date in dd-mm-yyyy format. For example, if today's date is "03-07-2017", it will increment the date by 3 days (as mentioned in the command shown in above example snippet) and would return "06-07-2017".

Comment: That's a Linux-only method... The flag `-d` means something very different on FreeBSD, for example.

Answer (score 13):

In Ansible 2.4 you can use `strftime` to accomplish this by using epoch times and then converting back to a string using the `strftime` filter.

For example, taking one day as 86400 seconds, to add 3 days would be:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ '%Y-%m-%d' | strftime( ( ansible_date_time.epoch | int ) + ( 86400 * 3 )  ) }}"
```

For minutes, the multiplier would be 60 seconds, and the datetime format string at the start should include the appropriate time granularity (e.g. %H, %M, %S, ...).

There is some documentation on this filter [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/docs/docsite/rst/playbooks_filters.rst#combination-filters).