# How to extend account expiration date of an user via Ansible?

Tags: bash, shell, ansible, redhat

I am very new to Ansible (still learning).

We have a script to create new a user, provide sudo access, define a password to be changed on first login, user details, account expiry date and then define password expiry information:

```yaml
---
- name: Create user with key
  hosts: all
  user: ansible
  sudo: True

  vars:

    password: $6$VhuG16emtCgF0zrK$dzE8swYNnLQeUkdgcgpTqr0stY8enepxcske8ATLAERjORpKkqYcGD6r6ssTNe4EdwwRs2UjjiAM/8tWCeEnN/
    raw: Password@1

  tasks:

  - name: Create New User
    user: name=TestUser comment="Test User" createhome=yes groups=wheel state=present password={{ password }}
  - command: chage -E 2023-10-18 TestUser
  - command: chage -d 0 TestUser
  - command: chage -M 120 TestUser
    register: newuser
```

We would define the hosts in the playbook command using `-i` and then name of the host file (which contains the IPs of the machines the users account will be create on) such as:

```sh
ansible-playbook create-newuser1.yml -i hosts.servers
```

Currently to extend the users account we have to go to each host and extend the account locally:

```sh
sudo chage -E 2023-12-28 TestUser
```

This may sound like a straight forward question to an "expert" in Ansible but I am unable to find information on how to use a similar script above (I have tried tweaking the script above and failed) to extend the existing user accounts expiration date and define the hosts either in a file or in the playbook command.

Tried searching [`user` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/user_module.html), unable to find anything. Also had quick glance in [Managing user accounts using Ansible playbooks](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_identity_management/managing-user-accounts-using-ansible-playbooks_configuring-and-managing-idm).

Still struggling.

**UPDATE 1**

Just had a brain wave would I just need to create a yml file (named: `extend-TestUser.yml`) stating:

```yaml
- command: chage -E 2023-12-28 TestUser
```

Then state this command:

```sh
ansible-playbook extend-TestUser.yml -i hosts.servers
```

Answer (score 4):

You may have a look into the documentation [`user` module – Manage user accounts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/user_module.html) and a minimal example playbook of

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: true
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    PASSWORD: 'Password@1'

  tasks:

  - name: Gather date and time only
    setup:
      gather_subset:
        - "date_time"
        - "!min"
    when: ansible_date_time is not defined

  - name: Configure or update user
    user:
      name: "TestUser"
      password: "{{ PASSWORD | password_hash('sha512') }}"
      comment: "Test User"
      createhome: true
      group: "DefaultGroup"
      groups: wheel
      state: present
      expires: "{{ '%s' | strftime( (ansible_date_time.epoch | int) + (86400 * 120)  ) }}"
```

It shows how to extend the expiration date from the current day by 120 days and or set a new password.

**Thanks To**

- [How to gather `ansible_facts` ... only when needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73470572/6771046)
- [Ansible - Increment date by `n` days or minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45473547/6771046)
- [Is there a Ansible function to convert date string to epoch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62783329/6771046)